# What should be done about automotive fluids killing grass?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

two big problems are happening due to automotive liquids, and the grass is dying because of it:
The other day I wan over a gas can, and there's a huge dead patch of grass in that spot where it happened.
The next day someone who bought my dad's car had a major coolant leak, of which most got on the driveway, but some got into the grass, and is now starting to form a dead patch.

What should be done about these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lawn self healed after time, but I've heard that using some oyster mushrooms in the area will treat oil spills.

see:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KO1WjFRL_XA
https://www.ted.com/talks/paul_stamets_on_6_ways_mushrooms_can_save_the_world?language=en